# Why is "nasm: error: unable to find utility "nasm", not a developer tool or in PATH" showing up?

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm

I am trying to learn assembly language for a Macbook Pro on Mac OSX 10.13.6, and I have just downloaded the NASM assembler. I read the manual and it told me to type

`nasm -h` into the Terminal for help

I did exactly that, however if I type that command or any other Terminal command which starts with nasm such as

```
nasm -f macho hello.asm
```

the same error message

```
nasm: error: unable to find utility "nasm", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

shows up. I am very new to this and I am trying to write my first assembly program, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where did you install `nasm` to?  This error message indicates that the shell could not find the `nasm` binary in its `PATH`.  This might be because you installed `nasm` into an unconventional location.

Comment: @fuz thanks! I re downloaded nasm with brew and now it is in the right path, and it works

Comment: Very good!  I've voted to close your question as your problem was just a simple configuration issue and has now been resolved.

Comment: brew reinstall nasm

Comment: there's also another issue related to this: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974320/how-can-i-get-nasm-to-work-as-a-command-in-terminal-in-macos you have to use /usr/local/bin/nasm