# How can I get nasm to work as a command in terminal in MacOS?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, nasm

I have been trying to get nasm to work as a command in terminal, but nothing seems to be working. I just keep getting the error:

```
nasm: error: unable to find utility "nasm", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

So, first, I tried updating my PATH variable. I tried editing the PATH variable:

```
safecrackers-MacBook-Pro-2:Library safecracker$ export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Libraries/nasm-2.14/
safecrackers-MacBook-Pro-2:Library safecracker$ nasm
nasm: error: unable to find utility "nasm", not a developer tool or in PATH
safecrackers-MacBook-Pro-2:Library safecracker$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Libraries/nasm-2.14/
safecrackers-MacBook-Pro-2:Library safecracker$ cd /Library/Libraries/nasm-2.14/
safecrackers-MacBook-Pro-2:nasm-2.14 safecracker$ ls
LICENSE     man1        ndisasm     rdf2ihx     rdfdump
README      nasm        rdf2bin     rdf2ith     rdflib
ldrdf       nasmdoc.pdf rdf2com     rdf2srec    rdx
```

I got the same error. Next, I tried installing nasm with homebrew:

```
safecrackers-MacBook-Pro-2:~ safecracker$ brew reinstall nasm
==> Reinstalling nasm 
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/nasm-2.14.02.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/safecracker/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/8581149c56e4f6aa40f6c17f75921aeec141f01373082bda3c7c8afa5cf5fbd5--nasm-2.14.02.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring nasm-2.14.02.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/nasm/2.14.02: 30 files, 2.7MB
safecrackers-MacBook-Pro-2:~ safecracker$ nasm
nasm: error: unable to find utility "nasm", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Again, I got the same error. I would love to finally figure this out.

Comment: brew reinstall nasm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid `/usr/bin/nasm` be found first in PATH use

```
$ /usr/local/bin/nasm
```

to find the one installed by `brew`, or

```
alias nasm=/usr/local/bin/nasm
```

and then

```
$ nasm
```

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this problem by:

```
brew reinstall nasm
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue with

```
sudo chown -R "your_username_folder" /usr/local/share/man/man8
```

On terminal

My brew was not configured properly, after this command and

```
brew install nasm
```

My NASM command is working properly

Done on MacOS Mojave Beta 4